# Date conversion in Oracle not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, date

ORACLE 10 g db: convert date format from

```
 02-JUL-14 
    to 
 02/JUL/14
```

I tried using the the select query below  to get "02/JUL/14" instead it shows "02-JUL-14":

```
SELECT ROUTINGNUM , to_date (EFFDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')  FROM hat;
```

Can anybody please help reading this.

Comment: Perhaps does it work, and your environment is not setup correctly to display it as you'd like. Perhaps trying to convert it in text shall allow you to see what is actually converted from your TO_DATE() output. Aside, perhaps shall you take an eye out your database parameters to see how you're set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if EFFDATE is a date column,

```
SELECT ROUTINGNUM , to_char( EFFDATE,'DD/MON/YYYY')  FROM hat;
```

if it is a String in the format DD-MON-YY

```
SELECT ROUTINGNUM , to_char( to_date( EFFDATE,'DD-MON-YY') ,'DD/MON/YYYY')  
FROM hat;
```

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE function is used for converting from String to Date type. Use TO_CHAR function instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your EFFDATE field is already a date type, then you just need to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
select eff_date from hat;
```

Or use TO_CHAR on EFFDATE

```
select to_char(eff_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from hat;
```

If you typically deal with a certain format of date, then you can change the default for your instance by setting one or more of the NLS init parameters.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
show parameter nls
```